# Removing irrelevant tags like 'option'

Tags: discussion, tags

There are lots of irrelevant tags that may confuse some programmers/users.

For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928254/is-it-possible-to-add-all-shipping-options-in-product-attribute-dynamically-mage), there is a use of the tag [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) which is completely not related to the question the user is asking for. The tag [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) has a description stating:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG. It is ambiguous and not helpful.

I tried to remove the tag in a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4930861) but my suggestion was rejected. Should I not remove this tag?

Comment: So, you remove the tag from that post then. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Yes I tried to remove but my suggestion was rejected

Comment: [This suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4930861) was rejected because you *only* removed the tag; you should address all issues with that post. The formatting and grammar of that post is *terrible* and you should have improved that too. Not to mention the other irrelevant tags on that post you left in place.

Comment: In other words, it wasn't rejected because the tag somehow should have remained.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, J Steen, I would have improved those things also. Thank you both of you.

Comment: i upvote ur question because -1 was not fair

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, tags like `option` are irrelevant and should be cleansed with fire.

**However** when you *do* remove such tags with suggested edits, you should *not just remove that one tag*.

The [post you edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928254/is-it-possible-to-add-all-shipping-options-in-product-attribute-dynamically-mage) has **terrible** grammar, formatting and at least 2 other tags that are irrelevant. When you suggest edits, you need to take into account that the post will be bumped up in the active questions queue and people will look at it again to see if it is worth answering, and that reviewers will have to spend time to review your changes. **Make it worth their time**.

I've edited the post now; compare [my version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23928254/2) to what [your version](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4930861) looked like.