# What is special about the `undefined` tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

For some reason I encountered the `undefined` tag for the first time earlier today, and I am not sure why the community seems to keep it, whereas an old tag like `option` was eradicated for [irrelevancy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256602/removing-irrelevant-tags-like-option) (agreeing with that conclusion).

The `undefined` tag is usually not alone, as it can apply to almost any language, framework, etc. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189598/undefined-method-nilnilclass/34189782#34189782) used it alone, but the problem was really about the underlying language, so I added the `ruby` tag. Just `undefined` is overly generic, and the watchers of the target language may not be able to help without being more specific. And, well, I do not know anyone specialize in `undefined`.

So I wonder whether we should keep such a tag, and why. What is so special about it that justifies having it? Perhaps search based on multiple tags is an answer (e.g. `ruby` AND `undefined`). I would be interested in other reasons.

The why may be worth discussing more actually, as it could lead SO to add some tips (or automated recommendation) near the Tags field/label of the question creation form.

Comment: `undefined` is actually pretty unambiguous, it refers to something that is not defined.

Comment: See also: [When to burninate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)

Answer (score 1):

The tag already looks a bit ambiguous, not in terms of its description (the description is very plain and clear), but simply in terms of how people are frequently using it. For example, I see a number of C++ questions there relating to linkage which contradict the tag's description:

> A variable is undefined if it has not been assigned a value.

These questions are specifically about how linkers work in C and C++. In those cases, there's a difference between declaration and definition and it has little to do with initialization.

In C and C++, "undefined" would most likely be commonly interpreted as "undefined behavior" (a behavior not defined by the language standard) or "undefined symbol" (a symbol which is declared to the compiler but not defined for the linker), since those are problems frequent in those languages, not so much a variable having a value of `nil/null/none`.

<sub>*I just tried a search for `[c++][undefined]` after writing this paragraph and that's exactly what I got: a bunch of results relating to undefined symbols and undefined behavior.*</sub>

I think the tag is fine but sometimes wish there was a way to indicate that a tag cannot be used standalone. This tag can take on a rich meaning when combined with some programming languages. It's just kind of nondescript when used in isolation.

The one thing I'm tempted to do now is edit the tag to make it more general to fit the 300/3126 C and C++ questions asked under it which are, from a glance, practically *all* asking about undefined symbols and behaviors which have nothing to do with unassigned variables.

Perhaps a more suitable description would be like,

> "A variable or symbol or behavior is undefined if it is not defined."

Hmm, I could use a bit of help on the wording there, but even this one immediately above would at least make it so all the questions asked under this tag at least fit the tag.

Comment: That sounds great: "I think the tag is fine but sometimes wish there was a way to indicate that a tag cannot be used standalone." And same initial observation on C/C++. `undefined` mostly maps to undefined behaviours in those languages.